# Simplifying $e^{2\pi i/5} + e^{-2 \pi i/5}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials

I am meant to be finding the minimal polynomial of this, but I am interested in how we can simplify it first? Plugging it into wolfram, I see it equals $1/2 ( \sqrt{2} - 1).$ But I am not sure how I can I arrive at this equality algebraically?

Comment: Hint: find the obvious polynomial satisfied by $\,z = e^{2\pi i/5} \,$ then you'll notice something about $\,z + \frac{1}{z}\,$.

Comment: I believe the minimal polynomial for $z$ is $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ but I'm not sure what this tells me about $z + 1/z.$

Comment: @Mike It's not the *minimal* one, but the useful part is that it's [reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) (a.k.a. palindromic).